# Friend's answer about his favourite game

Tags: video-games

I was chatted with my friend on WhatsApp. I asked him what's his favourite game.
He answered:

`Awards are stars. Money are diamonds and orbs. Download levels.`

What's that game?

Comment: Unless I'm missing a hidden meaning to the clue, this really isn't a puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be

> Geometry Dash

Awards are stars,

> You get stars for completing levels

Money are diamonds and orbs

> Diamonds and mana orbs can be used to buy stuff

Download levels

> Levels can be downloaded for offline play

Comment: Yeah!My friend said it's that game!Thank you very much

Comment: If it is correct, then why not give the checkmark to jafe's answer @hahaboki